# how to test function inside if statement jasmin karma angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular7

I'm new at unit testing.
i have a component that call a service to display list of students.

```
 getListStudents() {
this.noteService.getStudents({}).subscribe(res => {
  this.students= res
})}
```

then i call this fucntion in ngOnInit()

```
 if(this.currentUser.Type == 'Teacher'){
this.getListStudents()
}
```

without the if statement the test is correct but with the if statement it broke

this is my test

```
  it('should call the service  getStudents', () => {
component.currentUser={ "Type": "Teacher"}
let mock = [{
  "ID": 22,
  "name": "paul"
}]
let service: NoteService = TestBed.get(NoteService);
  spyOn(service, 'getListStudents').and.returnValue(of(mock));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.students.length).toBe(1)
 });
```

i got error Cannot read property 'Type' of null and when i remove if statement from ngOnInit it work as expected what i'am doing wrong?
Please suggest me a solutions to solve this problem.thank you

Comment: Maybe you can use `fixture.detectChanges();`  after define component.currentUser ? I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer =)  , but i still get component.students.length=0

Comment: Try defining `component.currentUser={ "Type": "Teacher"}` in a beforeEach statement. It worked for me.

Comment: thank you again for your answer =) it broke after fixture.detectChanges(); and i got error TypeError: Cannot read property 'Type' of null

Comment: You need initialize currentUser property in constructor()

Comment: thank you a lot  for this answer  lorenago =)) that was the problem

Comment: You're welcome.
Please Up vote if I help you.

Comment: yes your answer was very usefull  thank you very much but i need 15 reputation to upvote comments =(

Comment: Ok, don't worry :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use synchronous testing, [as shown in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service)

```
it('should call the service  getStudents', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.currentUser={ "Type": "Teacher"}
  let mock = [{
    "ID": 22,
    "name": "paul"
  }]
  let service: NoteService = TestBed.get(NoteService);
  spyOn(service, 'getListStudents').and.returnValue(of(mock));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();
  expect(component.students.length).toBe(1)
}));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer =) it broke after fixture.detectChanges(); and i got error TypeError: Cannot read property 'Type' of null

Comment: This means that somewhere you wrote `this.currentUser = null`

Comment: i just have one test in my spec.ts  and i called component.currentUser={ "Type": "Teacher"} i didnt undrestand why null and when i logged component.currentUser.Type in the test  it contains Teacher

Comment: Your component might change the value. `null` is a very specific value taht can't be taken implicitly : if it's null, then you probably set it somewhere !

Comment: i should initialize currentUser property in constructor() that was the error =) thank you for ur  help and time trichetriche